# Is it correct to divide parsing into simple and complex?

Tags: terminology, interpreter

I understand "field splitting" (or alternatively "word splitting") as a *possible* part of a broader process named parsing, while field splitting is done on parsing in various shells via field separation programs (such as IFS on Bourne shell and derivates).

Is it correct to divide parsing into simple and complex while simple doesn't include "field splitting" and complex does?

Comment: Are you asking a technical question or a philosophical / nomenclature question? Will an answer on unix/linux mean anything? I am just trying to get at the purpose of the question. You want to define parsing in terms of field splitting?

Comment: I am asking a technical question about shell, primarily about Bourne and derivates. About your last question; I don't. Stephen's answer below addresses basically any thought (internal question) I had on this. I suggest to give him an upvote for the ordinality, clarity and elegant detailing (I can't upovte).

Comment: I particularly agree with @Stephen Kitts last sentence. Perhaps that is what I was trying to get at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [the Shell Command Language section of POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), which specifies in detail how the shell should parse its input.

Field splitting is a component of word expansion, which is a small portion of command-line parsing in shells. Field splitting [only applies to the result of certain word expansions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) (tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion).

Parsing itself *always* involves input splitting in one form or another; this is usually referred to as lexical analysis or tokenisation, and can be merged into parsing (this is referred to as scannerless parsing). In the shell, tokenization happens before field splitting; see [Token Recognition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03).

Given that field splitting is a small subset of the overall parsing, it doesn’t seem all that relevant to qualify the parsing as simple or complex based on whether field splitting occurs or not.

Comment: I thank you dearly for the answer which I find ordinal, clear and elegant. I understand your recommendation above but sadly I don't have the mental capacity to collect data from such a huge text as the one you linked to (even if a "Table of contents" would have been added to it); if it was a printed book I would buy it gladly (I guess). Normally I can efficiently process data from documents not exceeding 10,000 bytes. I need my learning modular and well-stepped. Perhaps the fact that my native language is not English (and far from English) has something to do with that.

Comment: There’s a [table of contents](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html) but I understand what you mean ;-). POSIX is available in print, but it’s shockingly expensive (over $1,000 for non IEEE-members). There are other similar explanations of shell parsing in more digestible chunks, *e.g.* [in the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Syntax.html). There are probably books which explain this too, perhaps in a language you’d be more comfortable with!

Comment: This is one of the rare cases (at least for me) where a table of contents for a webpage is not in the webpage itself (and isn't named "table of contents"); perhaps it's some new way to format books online; well, I am comfortable with English, just not with webpages in that size... I need the information more modular...

Comment: The table of contents is separate because it’s designed to be viewed using frames (!): https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/